# Plone REST API: How do I manipulate user on plone by making REST calls on plone?

Tags: plone

We want to create user on plone from my java application, so how do I do that?
Have gone through https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi, but have not getting clear view.

I want to use REST client in java which can call on plone to create, update, delete, get user.

So can I get any example how to manipulate Plone users from my java application?

There is also availability of Json API, XML-RPC,Plone API(not suitable in our java app) but again for user manipulation it won't suits our requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

plone.restapi is still in pre-alpha stage, therefore not all features have been implemented. Unfortunately there is not user/group endpoint yet.

If you need one now I'd recommend to create your own with plone.rest. Or even better create a pull request for plone.restapi, so we can include it in the upcoming release.

I created a feature request on the repo where we can keep track of the progress:

https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi/issues/120

UPDATE: I implemented a basic @users endpoint:

https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi/pull/121